# Calling Array from class PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, function, class

So I'm trying to call an array which is generated from a database, here is the function in the class file:

```
public function select($array) 
{
   try 
   {
       $result ="SELECT id,make,model FROM cars";

       $stmt = $this->db->query($result);
       $array = $stmt->fetchAll();
   } 
   catch (PDOException $e) 
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

and here i'm trying to call the array, at least I am, quite new to this.

```
    include ('CarsDb.class.php');
    $db = new CarsDb();
    $db->connect();
    $carArray = $db->select($array);
    var_dump($carArray);
```

Now the var_dump just shows NULL, however if I put a var_dump in the function it'll show the array on my page, so can anyone help me?

Comment: return statement is missing in select function ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a value from your function. Do this.

```
public function select($array) {
    try {
        $result ="SELECT id,make,model FROM cars";
        $stmt = $this->db->query($result);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(); //Return value here
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And now this should work.

```
include ('CarsDb.class.php');
$db = new CarsDb();
$db->connect();
$carArray = $db->select($array);
```

Comment: That's got it working, thank you very much, saved me a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: @JayBhatt please consider the case when try block fails.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan The array returned by the function is initialized only if the query succeeds. If an exception is thrown the array will be empty. Rather then returning empty values the code should handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Return array from the select function

```
public function select($array=array()) {
try {

    $result ="SELECT id,make,model FROM cars";

    $stmt = $this->db->query($result);
    $array = $stmt->fetchAll();



} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
return $array;

}
```